# model can converge easly but prediction result is very poor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

by using transfer learning model,it converged very easily in tensorflow but taking single image for prediction that result is wrong

When i give trained image for prediction it also show wrong result

batchsize=32
input shape(32,256,256,3)
output classess=19

```
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
                                                  include_top=False,
                                                   weights='imagenet')


    feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)


    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)


    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(19,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    prediction_batch = prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)



    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      base_model,
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      global_average_layer,
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      prediction_layer  
    ])

    base_learning_rate = 0.0001
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    logdir="logs1/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

    model.fit_generator(train_ds,steps_per_epoch=100,epochs=20,validation_data=test_ds,validation_steps=100,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Data/testimg.jpg')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = plt.subplot(5,5,1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (256,256))
img=img.reshape(0,256,256,3)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
predictions=model.predict(img)



    predictions = model.evaluate(test_ds,steps=50)
```

output of evaluate:
50/50 [==============================] - 18s 350ms/step - loss: 9.8796e-06 - accuracy: 1.0000

[The Accuracy curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QERs4.png)

[the loss curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIhzz.png)

Comment: add your loss and accuracy curve

Comment: May be there is something wrong in preprocessing your test images. Like you may be forgot to divide the test image by 255.0 . Check the array of train image and test image.

Comment: @furcifer i have added the loss and accuracy curve. please review

Comment: @Pygirl divided the image by 255. but still prediction is poor. The mistake is in preprocessing image before prediction. but cant understand the mistake

Comment: In preprocessing steps what you are actually doing? because This type of thing happened to me also in 2-3 cases where my test array were not same as train set because of preprocessing.  Did you convert your train set into gray images or using as rgb ?

Comment: Moreover you are overfitting it seems may be your model is not learning anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your training seems okay, except the model is overfitted. Maybe Xception is a bigger model than you need, try with smaller base models such as mobilenet_v2, try training for fewer epochs.
2. Use data augmentation to increase your training samples (2-3 times). https://github.com/mdbloice/Augmentor
3. Your test accuracy is 100%. So, your model is definitely okay.

```
output of evaluate: 50/50 [==============================] - 18s 350ms/step - loss: 9.8796e-06 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

**(1.00 == 100%)**

4. Your inference method is not right. You need to apply the same pre-processing for test images, which you used while training.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Data/testimg.jpg')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = plt.subplot(5,5,1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (256,256))
img=img.reshape(1,256,256,3) # img.reshape(0,256,256,3) <- this line should give you error
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

img = img/255. # only use this if you used the same pre-processing while training

predictions=model.predict(img)
print(predictions)
print(f'predicted class: {np.argmax(predictions[0])}')
```